# Did a ship model used in Star Wars (1977) have Playboy pinups in its cockpit?

Tags: star-wars, special-effects

The 1999 tome [Uncle John's Legendary Lost Bathroom Reader](https://books.google.com/books/about/Uncle_John_s_Legendary_Lost_Bathroom_Rea.html?id=OdxLduEdxmcC) has an article on Star Wars which claims

> The models were so detailed that one of them even had Playboy pinups in its cockpit.

(p. 434)

If this is true, which model was it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in the [Tantive IV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tantive_IV#Origin_and_design) blockade runner and shown in [this video](https://youtu.be/uxpOIvX6X5A?t=53) from press coverage of the Australian leg of the Where Science Meets Imagination tour.

Comment: Your reference is a community maintained page, can you find anything more official on the matter or at least track Wikipedia’s sources since it cites on for this claim?

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot I've added a video link that actually shows the pinup...

Comment: https://www.bluemilkspecial.com/comic/captain-antilles-1-2/ this link indicates that the model was revamped, including the addition of a Star Wars poster and a playboy-style pinup. It wasn't in the original film